# Can't Scale a Small Image in GIMP

Tags: gimp, resize

I am using Gimp and I've created a 16x16 px image of a star. I am trying to use it as decoration for a Space Invader image I'm working on. I want it to keep it's wonderful blocky-ness and look like it's from an old video game. Instead, what's happening is it's becoming fuzzy and it looks terrible. An image of the star is below. That's what I want it to look like when it is inserted into the image, but it has to be bigger, since the image is 2560x1440.
[image]

And here is what is looks like when I try to scale it up.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have been using GIMP for a long time, but for whatever reason, this is not working for me.

Comment: Doing it the way you did is always going to lead to this blurriness.  Make the star as a vector or make it at the final size you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

- Image > Scale Image

Assign your final dimensions and turn off interpolation.

- Interpolation: none